# Copying info from the device manager to the clipboard

Tags: windows-xp, clipboard, device-manager

I have a Logitech webcam, which I can plug into my Windows XP machine via USB.
When I open the Device Manager, I can select the webcam and choose Properties-->Driver-->Driver Details. This gives me the following list of driver filenames:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\logishrd\WUApp32.exe
[25 more filenames...]
C:\WINDOWS\TWAIN_32\QuickCam\reset.wav

My question is, is there any way to copy this list to the clipboard? Copying it by hand is a drag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install this Software, then sort by Product name, then multiple select the drivers associated with the device and right click on one of the highlighted items, you will have several options to export or copy.

Webcam drivers can be Microsoft drivers, so it may be a little harder to sort them out.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/driverview.html

.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **[Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/)** or **[Microsoft OneNote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/)** or some other tool with OCR capabilities, then take a screenshot and tell the program to `Copy Text From Picture`.  I've tried it on some screenshots, and it works very well, at least in OneNote 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but - Run "msinfo32" and have a look if you see the same drivers.

old:AFAIR there is no way of copying it (on XP), you could take a screenshot and OCR it eg. http://www.free-ocr.com/

Comment: Is there any way to copy it on Windows 7?

Comment: Not in the driver tab, but in the details you can right click and copy. No idea why they didn't include it everywhere...

Comment: Thanks for suggesting msinfo32; it didn't give me quite the same information, though.